# Android: how to make string-array to be a reference to another string-array?

Tags: android, xml, reference, arrays

I can make string to be a reference to another string just like that:

```
<resources>  
    <string name="my_string">My String</string>  
    <string name="my_alias">@string/my_string</string>  
</resources>
```

And i tried to make string-array reference the same way:

```
<string-array name="my_string_array">
   <item>1</item>
   <item>2</item>
   <item>3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="my_string_array_alias">@array/my_string_array</string-array>
```

But this does not work, unfortunately. I tried to use this array and alias in `ListPreference`:

```
<ListPreference
   android:key="my_key"
   android:title="@string/my_title"
   android:entries="@array/my_string_array_alias"
   android:entryValues="@array/my_string_array"
   android:dialogTitle="@string/my_dialog_title" />
```

and `entries` is just an empty array. Of course, i can make both `entries` and `entryValues` to take the same array, but i like it to be a different ones.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the [Android dev site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources).

> Note: Not all resources offer a mechanism by which you can create an alias to another resource. In particular, animation, menu, raw, and other unspecified resources in the xml/ directory do not offer this feature.

It's a little vague but I believe this means the framework doesn't support it.